# Where do I put the Oracle Instant Client 11.2 SDK Symlinks?

Tags: macos, oracle, perl, 64-bit, instantclient

Oracle finally released the [64-bit Instant Client 11.2 for OS X](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) last week. I got it all installed and set up on Mountain Lion, and `sqlplus` works great. However, I can't build anything with the SDK.

For past versions of Instant Client, to build stuff like [DBD::Oracle](https://metacpan.org/module/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.56/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Macos.pod#Instructions-for-10.6.x-Snow-Leopard-), the secret was to create a `/b/` directory (yes, in the root directory) with the appropriate symlinks. On Snow Leopard, one needed to create `/b/227/rdbms/lib` as a symlink to `$ORACLE_HOME`. Another, older document in my company's Wiki talks about `/b/729/rdbms/lib`. Neither of these works the 11.2 Instant Client, IME. Sadly.

I tried `grep`ing the Instant Client libraries, and there I do see a reference to `/ade/b/2649109290/oracle/rdbms/lib`, but that doesn't work, either.

So what magical combination of hard-coded directories and symlinks do I need to put into my root directory in order to build on top of this thing?

Comment: Oy, it looks as though [this release is broken](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10834318). FFS Oracle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the [latest release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html), I did not need to create those hack symlinks at all. WINNING!

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OSX you normally use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the libraries. Also watch this thread on OTN: [Thread: OS X Users! 11gR2 Oracle Instant Client 32 & 64-bit is now available](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2493519). There is an unresolved reference to _C_SendHTTPRequest.